# How can I create a 2sxc app that has a listing and details that open in a modal?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I want to create a 2sxc app that has a listing of items. When a user clicks on an item, it should open the details view in a modal window.

However, I don't want to simply load all items into the page and have a JS open the modal. Ideally, I would want the modal to load the content only when it's called. Also, ideally the URL would still in place similar to how there's a listing and details templates in an app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done :)

It basically needs 3, optionally 5 steps

1. Open a DNN page without a layout
2. (optional) make sure only your module will be on the popup using `mid=...` parameter
3. Make sure you add the id/name-id/guid of the details in the link such as `post=...`
4. Create the razor view which shows the details, ensure it appears when the parameter is added
5. (optional) Create different urls for google / user so user sees the popup, google indexes a real page with the details view

#### 1. Empty Skin / Layout

The trick is to open the page using the DNN parameter to either switch to the layout-free skin (print), or to another custom skin. This allows you to start with an "empty" page without stuff around it. Either use `popUp=true` in the url (the `Up` must have an upper case U) or a skin parameter to choose another skin

#### 2. - 4 MID, url-parameter, name in url to select view

This MID is common - if you have mid=... DNN will not load any other modules on the page.

Same with the named url parameter for the details-id and view switching, so I won't document this in detail.

#### 5. Different details for Google vs. Interactive

In case you want google to index the details view, that would probably want the indexed page to have a layout. So create a link to the details without the special popup, and on-click only change it to open the link with the popup feature.